# How to remove all axis from plot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm new to gnuplot and I want to remove all of the axis and borders from the a plot. I've turned off borders, xtics, & ytics but I'm still getting an x-axis in my plot.

```
gnuplot> unset border
gnuplot> unset ytics
gnuplot> unset xtics
gnuplot> set samples 1000
gnuplot> set polar

        dummy variable is t for curves
gnuplot> plot [0:10*pi] 10+2*sin(56*pi*t/20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following commands:

```
unset raxis
unset rtics
```

Check `help raxis` and `help rtics`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following:

```
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
```

Greetings

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.